# JavaFX : constrained_resize_policy not applied to TableView

Tags: layout, javafx, tableview

**Update : Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example**

In my app, I deal with many table views and use the `constrained_resize_policy` in almost each of them. But in only one case, I cannot figure out why it is not applied. All my columns are shrinked even without specifying a pref/min/maxWidth.

**The related FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.* ?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import java.net.* ?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxtests.FXMLController">    
   <children>
        <TableView fx:id="regiTable" styleClass="content">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol" editable="false" resizable="false" styleClass="regimen-column" text="Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="isDefaultCol" editable="false" resizable="false" styleClass="regimen-column" text="Is default template" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="intervalCol" editable="false" resizable="false" styleClass="regimen-column" text="Time interval" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="activeOnOffCol" editable="false" resizable="false" styleClass="regimen-column" text="On/Off&#10;active" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="activeTWCol" editable="false" resizable="false" styleClass="regimen-column" text="Time window&#10;active" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="activeTICol" editable="false" resizable="false" styleClass="regimen-column" text="Time interval&#10;active" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="activeDoWCol" editable="false" resizable="false" styleClass="regimen-column" text="Days of week&#10;active" />
            </columns>
            <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
            </columnResizePolicy>
        </TableView>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Update** : In my project, the associated controller uses the `setCellFactory` and `setCellValueFactory`, but even without any logic the problem persists. The controller for this example is empty.

Here is the result I got **in my project** :
[image: Result with resize policy]

But I expect that every column has the same width and that there's no empty space. Did I miss something ?

Comment: It's *probably* unrelated, but your table cell is not properly implemented. Your `updateItem(...)` method *must* call `super.updateItem(item, empty);` and *must* deal with all possibilities (i.e. you need to call `setGraphic(null)` if `item==null`). It may be that failing to call the superclass method means the cells are not getting sized properly, causing the column sizing and layout to fail.

Comment: (As an aside, you can cut your code down by a huge amount with no loss of readability if you use lambda expressions.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @James_D, but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue. Anyway I will keep that in mind, I always "forget" to call the `super` in those cases.

About the lambda expressions, I would LOVE to use them, but because of the project constraints (Framework for multi-platform) I can't use them now because they are not supported :(

Comment: It might be tricky, but I recommend you try to create a [MCVE].

Comment: I already have one. It's the same code (almost) but only with the required elements. I did it for test purposes because I was wondering if the `BorderPane` wasn't interfering with the layout. Do I update the question or post the code somewhere else ?

Comment: [edit] your question to include that instead of the code you posted.

Comment: @James_D Question has been updated and can be tested only with the FXML file.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like somehow the initial sizing is getting vetoed due to the columns not being resizable, which shouldn't really happen. I don't have a workaround though... You could try only setting resizable to false once they are shown, but it would get a bit ugly.

Comment: I guess this is the only way to achieve this. Can you post your last comment as an answer, so this way I can accept it ?

Comment: Well... it's not a very good answer. If I get some time I might try to figure out something better, and obviously others may have better ideas. I think it's best left open for now.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your columns should be resizable

Comment: Deleting the `resizable="false"` of the first column didn't fix it.

Comment: and if you will remove all resizable="false" and set prefWidth="-1"?

Comment: Didn't fix it either. Also, in another view of my project, I have all the columns set to `resizable="false"` except one and it works. Are you trying what you propose before answering ?